# Linking to Child Actions Using Fragments

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm implementing a new site in MVC 5, and we're combining old content into one long, flowing page with fragment links (`#ChildAction`). I've opted to use `Controller.Index` as the primary page, which then has content, and then calls the child actions (with `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute.

My menus are generated by my own custom code for now (I couldn't find a way to make MvcSitemapProvider do what I want, and couldn't find anything else), but I'd like to somehow be able to generate my actions url as a fragment using `Url.Action`, like `Controller#Action`, instead of `Controller/Action`. What's the best way to achieve? Bonus points for coming up with a menu solution as well.

Should I just stick to writing my own `Url.MyAction` extension method, with my own custom Menus?

Answer (score 2):

Since fragments are client-side only, the only way you could potentially make this work is to make your child action calls from JavaScript. Browsers do not send fragment information to the server when requesting URLs, so there would be no other way for the application to understand which action you are requesting.

That said, if you did use MvcSiteMapProvider, you could use a [custom attribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Custom-Attributes-on-a-Node) to configure your fragment data and modify the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/SiteMapNodeModel.cshtml` to output the fragment at the end of the URL. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509679/mvc-sitemapprovider-hash-fragment#25513163) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did look at that, but I've decided to keep my own menu system for now.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but the link to the answer did help. Thank you for helping me solve my problem in a round about way!

Answer (score 0):

I've opted to use my own menu system, and rolled my own `@Url.MyAction` method:

```cs
public static string MyAction(this UrlHelper urlHelper,
                              [AspMvcAction] string action,
                              [AspMvcController] string controller) {
    // My MenuItem will use "Index" for Action and the anchor will be the
    // subMenu item, so GetMenuItem searches both anchors and action name
    MenuItem menuItem = MenuBuilder.GetMenuItem(action, controller);
    if (menuItem == null) return null;
    return urlHelper.Action(menuItem.ActionName, menuItem.ControllerName) + "#" + menuItem.Anchor;
}
```

Note that `[AspMvcAction]` and `[AspMvcController]` are JetBrains Annotations to allow for autocomplete when using ReSharper