# Adding anchor link to mvc.sitemap file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, anchor, single-page-application, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a MVC single page website and I have an mvc.sitemap file:

```
 <mvcSiteMapNode  title="Home" controller="Home" action= "Index"> 
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

I want to add anchor links to this page, is this a good way to do this?

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")#services">services</a> 
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
```

I would prefer not to edit the page at run time for performance reasons.

Comment: If this is a single-page-application, how do you "render" the razor syntax? single-page-application used to run on client-side, instead of server-side

Comment: ok I am using the single page as a home page I have a 6 sections in the home page and I have a 6 tables on db and 6 models and I have one model to collect the 6 models and I use the last model to render the data on the home page --------------- for each section I have a sub count of pages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mvc sitemapprovider hash fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509679/mvc-sitemapprovider-hash-fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- add key to the xml node

```
 <mvcSiteMapNode  title="portfolio" controller="Home" action= "Index" key="portfolio" />
```

then editgo to shared>>display tamplates
and edit **SiteMapNodeModel.ascx** like that

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`1[[MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.SiteMapNodeModel,MvcSiteMapProvider]]" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models" %>

<% if (Model.IsCurrentNode && Model.SourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"].ToString() != "MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper")  { %>
    <%=Model.Title %>
<% } else if (Model.IsClickable) { %>
    <% if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Description)) { %>
        <a class="page-scroll"  href="<%=Model.Url%>"><%=Model.Title %></a>
    <% } else { %>
        <a class="page-scroll"  href="<%=Model.Url%>#<%=Model.Key%>" title="<%=Model.Description%>"><%=Model.Title %></a>
    <% } %>
<% } else { %>
    <%=Model.Title %>
<% } %>
```

that is all