# Multiple nodes with the same URL 'example.org/contact/#location' were found. SiteMap requires that sitemap nodes have unique URLs

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

How to get MvcSiteMapProvider to support hash fragment (named Ancors) nodes, and avoid the Multiples nodes error?

I'm setting URLs explicitly with the "url" attribute/property of the node.

I've been using the same sitemap for years with MvcSiteMapProvider v3 without any problem. This error appeared while upgrading to v4, since the project is targeting .NET 4.5 now.

By the way, adding a querystring is not an answer, but a dirty work around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mvc sitemapprovider hash fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509679/mvc-sitemapprovider-hash-fragment)

Comment: Not a duplicate because the other question doesn't address the error "Multiple nodes with the same URL". Probably because it was regarding v3, where this wasn't an issue and would work just fine.

Comment: Actually, yes it does. As pointed out in the answer, fragments are a client-side feature that most browsers do not send along with the request to the server. Therefore, there is no way for `MvcSiteMapProvider` to tell 2 nodes apart that only differ by fragment. It "worked" in v3 because of a bug that allowed multiple nodes with the same URL. But actually, it only matched the first registered node every time.

Comment: Also, in the other post it says "you can accomplish this by adding a custom attribute to the node and then modifying the node template to output the fragment in the view" BUT it can't be accomplished in v4 because of the error.

Comment: I don't think there was a bug on v3 for allowing multiple nodes with the same URL, it's actually quite the opposite (a bug now), as MvcSiteMapProvider must provide support for fragments. Every modern site navigation menu use fragments. Regarding the actual issue, which was to identify the node for breadcrumb purposes, It can be accomplished with javascript or cookies BUT this error must go away.

Comment: A `SiteMap` is a ***model*** that represents server-side navigation points. If you want to edit the client-side, then edit the ***views*** in `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates`. You can use custom attributes to send data to your view. Microsoft's original implementation also disallows duplicate URLs, which is why this has been done. The design depends heavily on the uniqueness of the nodes, and as I mentioned since fragments are not sent back to the server they cannot make a node unique and will therefore match the wrong one (or none at all).

Comment: It can't be accomplished using /Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates

Comment: Why not? You can add as many non-server-side navigation points as you want to the display templates. Please add the details of the specific issue to your question.